# Produce time series data in a JSON file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to produce the following JSON structure via python.  This was taken from [the mongoDB web site](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb)

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: { 0: 999999, 1: 999999, …, 59: 1000000 },
    1: { 0: 2000000, 1: 2000000, …, 59: 1000000 },
    …,
    58: { 0: 1600000, 1: 1200000, …, 59: 1100000 },
    59: { 0: 1300000, 1: 1400000, …, 59: 1500000 }
  }
}
```

So far I have the following:

```
import json
import random

data = {}  
data['type'] = "memory_used"
data['timeStamp_Hour'] = "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z" 
data['values'] = []

for x in range(59):
    for y in range(59):
        data['values'].append({  
        x : round(random.uniform(0, 100), 2)
        })

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Which gives me:

```
{
  "type": "memory_used",
  "timeStamp_Hour": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "values": [
    {
      "0": 9.8
    },
    {
      "0": 33.61
    },
    ......
```

I am not sure how to structure the loop so I can append to the values section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `values` is meant to be `Dict[int, Dict[int,int]]`  rather than a list as you have.

```
...
data['values'] = {}

for x in range(59):
    d={}
    for y in range(59):
        d[y]=round(random.uniform(0, 100), 2) 
    data['values'][x]= d
...
```

Comment: I get a syntax error on the line d[y]=round(random.uniform(0, 100), 2) )

Comment: You had an extra ) at the end of that line, works without it.